# JFoenix a Bug maybe with javaFx control

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, java-9, jfoenix

moved my project to JDK9 ,I started get this exception which I beleive is a bug .. in my project I have a JFXDatePicker , in my module-info.java, I requires 2 packages  "requires javafx.controls; " & the JFoenix "requires com.jfoenix;" for the JFXDatePicker ..

the exception is this:

```
  Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 
  java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class 
  com.jfoenix.controls.behavior.JFXGenericPickerBehavior (in module 
  com.jfoenix) cannot access class 
  com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ComboBoxBaseBehavior (in module 
  javafx.controls) because module javafx.controls does not export 
  com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior to module com.jfoenix
```

The thing is I have no ComboBox used in my project .

The solution was to use DatePicker of javaFx though it was not that looking good as the JFXDatePicker .

Comment: Do you use the Java 9 version of JFoenix? Seems to be a issue with module access...

Comment: @fabian...yes Jfoenix jar for java 9 . Actually it seems modules conflict , cuz I'm not using ComboBox at all .